# I am scraping data with Selenium from FLIPKART.COM ecommerce site. I am unable to click on Read More button on the page

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want to click on above mentioned elements and scrape the data.
[link1](https://www.flipkart.com/oneplus-nord-ce-2-lite-5g-black-dusk-128-gb/p/itm7acae55b999e6?pid=MOBGDWFEAHHTW8CF&lid=LSTMOBGDWFEAHHTW8CFENS3HD&marketplace=FLIPKART&q=Oneplus+Nord&store=tyy&srno=s_1_1&otracker=search&otracker1=search&fm=organic&iid=c71b7472-b5e8-4c3e-8017-5529a2b878ef.MOBGDWFEAHHTW8CF.SEARCH&ppt=hp&ppn=homepage&ssid=2sgyf82e7k0000001653155547982&qH=53863d4d978d5074) and [link2](https://www.flipkart.com/oneplus-nord-ce-2-lite-5g-black-dusk-128-gb/p/itm7acae55b999e6?pid=MOBGDWF8GJTFAXVH&lid=LSTMOBGDWF8GJTFAXVH49UKTF&marketplace=FLIPKART&q=Oneplus+Nord&store=tyy&srno=s_1_2&otracker=search&otracker1=search&fm=Search&iid=c71b7472-b5e8-4c3e-8017-5529a2b878ef.MOBGDWF8GJTFAXVH.SEARCH&ppt=sp&ppn=sp&qH=53863d4d978d5074)

Correct Element: `class="_2KpZ6l _1FH0tX" Xpath of the element = //*[@id="container"]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[8]/div[4]/div/div[2]/button`

When I pass this path, I am getting this error:

> NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:

**My code:**

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('http://www.flipkart.com/')

close_login_popup = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/div/button')
close_login_popup.click()

search_mobile = driver.find_element_by_class_name("_3704LK")
search_mobile.send_keys('Oneplus Nord',Keys.ENTER)
```

Container which contains all the data about the product.

```
container = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("_4ddWXP")
```

clicking on product name

```
click_product = data.find_element(By.XPATH, './/a[@class="s1Q9rs"]').click()
```

clicking on read more -- this is not working

```
click_readMore = data.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"_2KpZ6l _1FH0tX").click()
```

Alternative codes I have tried to click on Read More button

`````
click_readMore = .find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[8]/div[4]/div/div[2]/button').click()

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@class="_2KpZ6l _1FH0tX"]')

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="_3dtsli"]//button')````
`````

Answer (score 1):

Please try this //button[translate(text(),'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')='read more']

Comment: not working..,,

Comment: this link open in new tab and i am unable to scrape anything from it.

Comment: have you tried above xpath?

Comment: It is working fine. If not still at your end please share the problem statement clear that I can suggest.

Comment: replace ```//button``` in the beginning with ```//span```. I tried and it is working. ("READ MORE" is a span element).

Answer (score 0):

this work

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument("--headless") #does not open the browser
option.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
option.add_argument('user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36')
option.add_argument("window-size=1500,1200")
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=option)
driver.get('https://www.flipkart.com/oneplus-nord-ce-2-lite-5g-black-dusk-128-gb/p/itm7acae55b999e6?pid=MOBGDWFEAHHTW8CF&lid=LSTMOBGDWFEAHHTW8CFENS3HD&marketplace=FLIPKART&q=Oneplus+Nord&store=tyy&srno=s_1_1&otracker=search&otracker1=search&fm=organic&iid=c71b7472-b5e8-4c3e-8017-5529a2b878ef.MOBGDWFEAHHTW8CF.SEARCH&ppt=hp&ppn=homepage&ssid=2sgyf82e7k0000001653155547982&qH=53863d4d978d5074')
try:
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 200);")
    el = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//button[normalize-space()='Read More']").click()
except: 
    try:
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 300);")
        el = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//button[normalize-space()='Read More']").click()
    except: pass
```